# GIS Layer Versioning In GeoServer

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs, geoext

i have developed the application for editing the map features online but i want the features to be saved as version of the layer not in original layer.this work is done using GeoExt +GeoServer+OpenLayers.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange reha. Please don't SHOUT. Use upper and lower case correctly.

Answer (score 3):

IanT, there is some experimental versioning code around in unsupported land, have a look at WFS-V (WFS versioning) and geogit